# HTTP/2 does not allows to write in folders in Drupal 7, how can I fix?

Tags: 7, files

I've recently changed from HTTP 1.1 to HTTP/2, as soon as i did it I was not able to create or edit files from backoffice (both image upload or css/js cache), but if I did it from FTP there is no problem

All the folders are 755 and all the files are 644 and I could not get other informations

Varnich cache is not installed on the server, what can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found, just needed to install suPHP module and configure it so apache could execute php with owner permissions instead of default user